# What happens on a force quit?

Tags: linux, process

I was using Eclipse. It hanged after a while. When the force quit dialog came up, I pressed on force quit.

Then, my Eclipse disappeared! I can't find any trace of it in my system.

What happened? What exactly does force quit do? I thought it works like `ctrl+alt+del.` But shouldn't it just close the hanged process instead of remove the whole software from my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force quit kills the application process and its sub processes forcefully. But it will not remove the actual files from your hard disk.

Comment: It did. `which eclipse` returns eclipse not found. Nor am I able find its folder.

I am currently re-installing the whole thing.

Comment: That is strange. Normally it should not happen.

Comment: @user657592 This time are you going to install Eclipse using your package manager (in Ubuntu it would be the Ubuntu Software Center) or are you going to download a file and install the file that you downloaded?

Comment: downloading the file & installing. Why? How does that matter?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't always keep track of what happens to the functionality of any Eclipse plugins that you may have installed when you upgrade a package that Eclipse uses. Then you'll have to find out about a plugin that isn't working the hard way after you find your code isn't working as expected. The easy way to do it is to use your package manager and then your package manager will keep track of any dependencies for you.